# Using Postmash plugin in Wordpress 3.3.1

Tags: plugins, posts

I want to be able to reorder posts and have them listed in this custom order from the category page.

I've downloaded and activated the [Postmash](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postmash-custom/installation/) plugin but am having problems with installation.

I've copied this text

```
<?php  
    $wp_query->set('orderby', 'menu_order');  
    $wp_query->set('order', 'ASC');  
    $wp_query->get_posts();  
?>
```

into index.php as instructed, but I don't understand where I need to use this line of code

```
<?php get_posts('orderby=menu_order&order=ASC'); ?>
```

to reorder my posts on the category page.

Assistance would be much appreciated!  TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this [Postmash](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/postmash/) plugin instead. Works perfectly without modifications to templates.